# SQL Group by and include count in group by clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I have table as follows

```
User ID | file
----------------
1       | File1    
2       | File2    
3       | File3    
4       | File4    
1       | File5    
1       | File6
3       | File7
----------------
```

Requirements is as follows

```
File Count  | Users
-------------------
1           | 100    
2           | 300    
3           | 800    
4           |  70    
5           |  20    
8           |   8
-------------------
```

So results should display the user count with files count.

It means, I have to include count into group by clause

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: your question is not understandable.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to say that you want to identify how many files each user has and then to produce a summary of how many users have 1 file versus how many users have 2 files, etc, and that's your final result? (And so the matching input sample should have 3544 rows?)

Comment: Your question is not clear, nor is it understandable.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, what i mean to say that i want to know the count of users who are in group of files count for e.g. there are 10 users who have only 1 files in system, 100 users with 2 files & so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you intended something like this (the count of the users with a certain number of files):

```
SELECT RC1 AS FILE_COUNT, COUNT(*) AS RC2 
FROM
(SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*) RC1 FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY USER_ID ) A
GROUP BY RC1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go! This will produce count of file for each user.

```
select userid, COUNT(filename) as FileCount from files
group by userid
```

---

If you are looking for users per file then here is updated answer

```
select count(userid) as usercount, filename from files
group by filename
```

Comment: But he wants the count of users per file.